# ERROR: syntax error at or near "." LINE 4: ON like.takerId = frame.likeId;

Tags: sql, postgresql, quoted-identifier

i have a table whose name is `like`. But whenever i have to select data from like, i was getting this error, i figured it out `public.like`..but when i try to join two tables

```sql
SELECT *
FROM frame
INNER JOIN public.like
ON like.takerId = frame.likeId;
```

i get this error

```sql
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 4: ON like.takerId = frame.likeId;
```

i also use public prefix but it throws

```sql
ERROR:  column like.takerid does not exist
LINE 4: ON public.like.takerId = frame.likeId;
           ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "like.takerId".
```

even if it is saying `column like.takerid does not exist` , then why it gives me `HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "like.takerId".` I dont know, i think it is problem with `like` table name, `like` is a sql syntax, and it assumes `like` and a sql syntax and throwing me error. Should I change my table name? Or is there any way to make sql case sensetive or how can i tell sql to ignore `like`. `public.like` is not working for joining table.

Comment: You're using *reserved words* as a names

Comment: I would recommend `likes`.  Plurals are much less likely to interfere with reserved words and keywords.  And, tables contain multiple entities, so a plural is appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `like` is a reserved keyword, you need to use [double quotes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) for each occurance of it (unless it's prefixed with the schema name as you found out)

```
SELECT *
FROM frame
  JOIN public.like ON "like".takerId = frame.likeId;
```

Or

```
SELECT *
FROM frame
  JOIN "like" ON "like".takerId = frame.likeId;
```

Or use an alias

```
SELECT *
FROM frame f
  JOIN "like" l ON l.takerId = f.likeId;
```

---

But in the long run you should find a different name for the table that does not require quoting.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely chose another name for your table. `LIKE` is a reserved command, and it is considered a bad practice to use it, although possible by using `"`, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE public."like" (id int);
INSERT INTO public."like" VALUES (42);
SELECT * FROM "public.like"
```

**EDIT**: As pointed out by @a_horse_with_no_name, specifying a schema in temporary tables won't work (check `db<>fiddle`), so only the table name should be between double quotes as corrected in the snippet above. For temporary tables just omit the schema:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE "like" (id int);
INSERT INTO "like" VALUES (42);
SELECT * FROM "like"
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e8ace44bca24f282f78c802cfaae9fd1)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I thought so at first, but it threw an error: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2cd7a9a1ae9b1990174b78bcfe3c98e8

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ah, now I see the issue... it does not work with `TEMPORARY tables :-P https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4822425a145eb66a873d5640bc487d78

Comment: you can't specify a schema for temporary tables.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for pointing out! It is amazing how simple things can get tricky.. I just corrected it. +1